# google analytics v4 on android crashing

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I am trying to track my app statistics using Google Analytics. I am trying to follow the tutorial at http://java.dzone.com/articles/working-google-analytics-api which several people have posted and said it works for them. Here is my code :

my app_tracker.xml file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
<span style="line-height: 1.5; font-style: inherit; font-weight: inherit;">
</span>

<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXX-1</string>

<string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>

<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

<integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">-1</integer>


<screenName name="game">game</screenName>
<screenName name="settings">settings</screenName>
</resources>
```

my global_tracker xml file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

<span style="line-height: 1.5; font-style: inherit; font-weight: inherit;">

</span>

<string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>

<integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">30</integer>

<bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>

<string name="games">games</string>
<string name="settings">settings</string>
</resources>
```

in my manifest file i have entered the following code block:

```
<meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

my Main activity looks like this :

```
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

((MyApplication)getApplication()).getTracker(MyApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

 }
```

The MyApplication class which the app should have is as follows

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {


private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXXXXXX-1";

private static final String TAG = "MyApp";

public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

public enum TrackerName {
APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
}

HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

public MyApplication() {
super();
}

synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
: (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
: analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

}
return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}
}
```

When the program is running, it crashes when it reaches the line

```
((MyApplication)getApplication()).getTracker(MyApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

in the main activity. I have spent weeks trying to find a way around this but no success. Can somebody please help me configure google analytics v4 in my android project?

**I'm editing this (as i'm getting the same issue) & here goes the logcat**

```
:10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mrana.send/com.mrana.send.HomeActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.mrana.send.SendApplication
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.mrana.send.SendApplication
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at com.mrana.send.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:73)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-29 15:31:13.062: E/AndroidRuntime(683):  ... 11 more
```

Line 73 is same line as op mentioned where it crashes the app.

Note:Im testing it on emulator. Does this feature requires to be tested on real devices (having play store installed)?

Comment: You would need to include the Logcat lines from the crash in order for us to really be able to figure out why it's crashing.

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your code. Like indenting correctly...

Comment: Reasons to edit this post were 1. Im facing exact same issue 2. Explanation provided for crash by op was less 3. I didn't want to waste the resuorces of s.o.   If it is against the rulkes of s.o. lemme know, will remove my edit.

Comment: Check your manifest. The issue is obvious.

Comment: yes, thx. i forgot to add mine Activity as Application (android:name="SendApplication)".

Comment: @Mohit , where in the Manifest file did you make your change ..can you please upload how your manifest looks like. i am failing to figure out where i need to edit to make my program work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Application name in manifest file.

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainApplication" >
 </application>
```